# Elementary Queue in java

Tags: java

Which is the most elementary queue in java. I just need enqueue and dequeue operations. My application is not concurrent. I find lot of confusing queue names [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Comment: You can always write your own, esp. if you only need enqueue and dequeue :)

Comment: @irrelephant: unnecesary, having quite simple implementations ready to use, as LinkedList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.util.LinkedList` is the simplest.

`java.util.ArrayDeque` is the fastest.

Though it doesn't apply to you, `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is the most bullet-proof in that you can have multiple threads all talking to it at the same time without worry.

Answer (score 9):

[LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is the most basic.